# Spaces not showing up in a string converter

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {
        String letter = input.substring(i,i+1).toLowerCase();
        if (letter.equals("a"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[0];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("b"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[1];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("c"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[2];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("d"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[3];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("e"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[4];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("f"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[5];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("g"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[6];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("h"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[7];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("i"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[8];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("j"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[9];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("k"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[10];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("l"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[11];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("m"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[12];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("n"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[13];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("o"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[14];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("p"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[15];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("q"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[16];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("r"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[17];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("s"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[18];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("t"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[19];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("u"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[20];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("v"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[21];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("w"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[22];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("x"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[23];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("y"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[24];
        }
        else if (letter.equals("z"))
        {
            encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[25];
        }
        else if (letter.equals(" "))
        {
            encrypted += " ";
        }
    }
```

This program is supposed to run through the letters of a string and see what letter it is, it is then supposed to switch that letter with the corresponding letter from the "encryptedAlphabet[]".  This works fine but I run into problems when I introduce spaces into the input string, it does not keep the spaces and stops after the first word. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a nitpick: It is easier, cleaner, and faster to use `else if (input.charAt(i) == 'a'){ `.

Comment: Does your input really contains the entire String with spaces? Try to output it to see if it is ok.

Comment: You can also just make this much smaller if you use input.charAt(i) - 'a' this would get you the index of the array right away you don't need to put 24 conditions. So you can say `if(input.charAt(i) == ' ') {encrypted += " "}; else{encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[input.charAt(i)-'a']}` if it is 'a', 'a' - 'a' would be 0 and same for the rest of the alphabet

Comment: how are you getting the input. Are you sure input contains full text with spaces.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole code so we can pin point the problem

Comment: The problem ended up just being in the input.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any problems with your code's behavior regarding spaces. I think there is some other problem with your input. Print it `System.out.println(input);` before executing the loop and check it's what you're expecting.

Your algorithm can be shortened to avoid all the repetition. Rather than doing lots of `if .. else` commands, you can calculate the index into the encrypted alphabet. Use the fact that the ASCII value of alphabetic characters are sequential, and calculate the index as `ch - 'a'`  (`'a' - 'a' = 0`, `'b' - 'a' = 1` etc.).

E.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char ch = input.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
    if (ch == ' ') {
       encrypted += ch;
    } else if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) {
       encrypted += encryptedAlphabet[ch - 'a'];
    } else {
       throw new Exception("Unsupported character: " + ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: true, but does not really answer the question.

Comment: I can't really answer the question without the OP posting more code. The code he posted works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to replace a space with a space, then why not change the final `else if` clause to be:

```
else {
    encrypted += letter;
}
```

Otherwise, other characters like an apostrophe might be omitted from the input too.

Comment: This does not answer the question although it is a cleaner way to solve the problem I suggest putting it in the comments of the question

Comment: @Thresh You're right that it doesn't directly answer "Any ideas?" as a question but it may well solve the problem of characters getting dropped, which I figure is what the author of this question wants to do.

Comment: The code is logically not faulty that's the issue, the problem with this question is that it does not have all the code, just the working part. I believe the problem is not in the presented code but rather the rest of it like how he is taking the input.